# How to set up U1 account after not receiving verification code?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I did not receive the verification code to complete the setup of my Ubuntu One account. What can I do to get it set up now?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this as described in the help section:

> ### I never received my verification code. Now what?
>
> To work around this use the "Forgot password" process:
>
> https://login.ubuntu.com/+forgot_password
>
> Once you complete that process, you can open the Ubuntu One Control
> Panel and click on the "I already have an account" link.

Reference: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/i-never-received-my-verification-code-now-what/

If you have more problems, you can find a lot of information in the FAQ section on Ubuntu One's website: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq